# Controle de threads para evitar lock

Tags: python, multithreading

Estou começando um [projeto de crawler](https://github.com/bruno-santiago/crawler) e a ideia dele é baixar todo o conteudo de um determinado website. Ele já tem algumas funcionalidades "utilizáveis". O que está me matando é, estou fazendo ele multithread, porém as Threads em um momento param e eu não sei como evitar.

Fiz alguns testes e constatei que as Threads ainda estão vivas. Continuam lá, mas parecem estar em um estado de lock.

Elas podem demorar 5 segundos ou 5 horas mas uma coisa é certa, ela vai entrar em lock. E eu gostaria de confiar no meu crawler a ponto de deixar ele rodando 24 horas por dia.

Então aqui vão os meus questionamentos:

**Existe alguma limite quanto ao número de Threads que eu posso utilizar?**

**Como eu evito que a minha Thread entre em Lock?**

```
class Fetcher(Thread):

    wait_time = 7
    dispatcher = None
    work = None

    def __init__(self, dispatcher, *args, **kwargs):
        Thread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.dispatcher = dispatcher
        self.wait_time = kwargs.get('wait_time', 7)
        self.start()

    def request_work(self):
        self.work = None
        if self.dispatcher.has_work():
            self.work = self.dispatcher.get_work()

    def do(self):
        if self.work is not None:
            self.fetch_url()

    def fetch_url(self):
        request = urllib2.Request(self.work.url)

        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            html = buffer(response.read())
            page = Page(self.work, html)
            page.save()
        except urllib2.URLError:
            self.dispatcher.fill_pool([self.work,])
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            self.dispatcher.fill_pool([self.work,])
        except:
            self.dispatcher.fill_pool([self.work,])

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.request_work()
            if self.work:
                self.do()
                time.sleep(self.wait_time)
```

**Dispatcher:**

```
class Dispatcher:        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pool = []

    def has_work(self):
        return len(self.pool) > 0

    def get_work(self):
        return self.pool.pop(0)

    def fill_pool(self, workload):
        self.pool = self.pool + workload
```

**Running Example:**

```
dispatcher = Dispatcher()
dispatcher.fill_pool(['url1', 'url2', 'url3'])
fetcher1 = Fetcher(dispatcher)
fetcher2 = Fetcher(dispatcher)
fetcher3 = Fetcher(dispatcher)
fetcher4 = Fetcher(dispatcher)
```

Coloquei esse exemplo a pedido do usuário Brumazzi, mas ele não irá rodar. Como dito anteriormente, o crawler que estou criando depende de todos os seus componentes para rodar sem o menor problema. E a classe `Page` faz parte do projeto, representando um objeto no banco de dados.

Comment: tem o código, mas não tem nada dizendo como usar, que tipo de parâmetro deve ser passado para a classe? onde informa a url? sem uma documentação ou comentários fica difícil fazer a depuração.

Comment: Brumazzi, infelizmente colocar todo o código do projeto aqui acho que será algo inviável. Sendo que nem tudo usa Thread e esse é o ponto. O que posso fazer é melhorar mais a descrição do projeto de maneira a facilitar a depuração. Porém só poderei fazer isso quando chegar em casa. E a pergunta é mais sobre o controle de Threads em si, o meu é apenas um exemplo, não precisa utilizar ele necessariamente.

Comment: Focando apenas na classe Fetcher, qual o tipo de parâmetro deve ser inserido na instancia? como python não especifica os tipos dos parâmetros, fica mais difícil entender as entradas e saídas do código. Tendo como rodar o código e ver erro, fica mais facil de dar uma resposta

Comment: Brumazzi, então, o projeto é completamente interligado. Existe o `Dispatcher` que basicamente é uma fila de urls a serem pesquisadas que alimenta o fetcher. Existe o `Fetcher` (que eu postei o código) que é o cara que vai na web e busca o conteudo daquela URL e alimenta o banco. O `UrlFinder` é responsável por destrinchar a pagina web que está armazenada no banco e encontrar mais Urls e alimentar o `Dispatcher`.

Comment: Posso postar o código do Dispatcher que é o parametro para o Fetcher, mas ele vai ter que ser alimentado na mão. E não existe 'erro' estourando, a Thread apenas congela. :(

Comment: Uma dica, não faça `return len(self.pool) is not 0` faça `return len(self.pool) > 0` ou `return len(self.pool) != 0` o `is` você só deve usar para comparar a identidade de dois objetos, não comparar os valores.

Comment: Muito obrigado @drgarcia1986, vou modificar isso no meu código assim que chegar em casa. Obrigado por apontar essa escorregada que eu dei ali. =)

Answer (score 4):

Você está usado uma lista que não é thread safe (`dispatcher.pool`) e compartilhando entre vários workers (`Fetcher`), isso pode ser um indicio do seu possível problema, tente trocar de uma lista simples para uma fila ([Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/queue.html)) thread safe.

Comment: Vou fazer isso. Você por acaso sabe se existe um limite de threads que eu posso utilizar? Se eu utilizar 3 ou 100 tanto faz? Ou existe um limite viável?

Comment: Acredito que o limite será de acordo com o limite do SO, porém, lhe recomendo trabalhar com no máximo duas thread por core do processador, já que os códigos "blocantes" vão estar presos pela GIL (o python irá liberar a GIL somente para tarefas de I.O.)